# PayPal "Error: 422 Unprocessable Entity" when processing cancellations with API

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

I was using PayPals cancellation API for subscriptions. It worked absolutely fine. Weirdly, I have started to get the following error while trying to cancel subscriptions through the API.

```
{
StatusCode: 422, ReasonPhrase: 'Unprocessable Entity', Version: 1.1, 
Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Connection: keep-alive
  Application_id: XXXXXXXXXXXXX
  Caller_acct_num: XXXXXXXXXXXXX
  Paypal-Debug-Id: XXXXXXXXXXXXX
  HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR: ccg13.slc
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
  Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate, no-cache, max-age=0
  Date: Thu, 15 Jul 2021 15:29:56 GMT
  Set-Cookie: l7_az=ccg13.slc; Path=/; Domain=paypal.com; Expires=Thu, 15 Jul 2021 15:59:56 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure
  Content-Length: 481
  Content-Type: application/json
}
}
```

Which, in plain English, according to PayPal means the following:

> "Error: 422 Unprocessable Entity
>
> This error means one of two things:
>
> - Your PayPal account must have an adequate balance to cover the payouts it is attempting to process.  Unlike personal PayPal accounts
>   that withdraw from a bank or credit card source, you must have a
>   sufficient existing PayPal balance to cover the referrals you are
>   attempting to pay out, or you will receive this error.  Also, know
>   that your PayPal sandbox account has a separate balance than your live
>   account, so make sure it is adequately funded as well prior to testing
>   with a sandbox account.
> - The currency code the funds are being sent in cannot be received by the recipient due to country or account regulations."

**Neither of which are relevant to me. I have more than enough funds available (in GBP), and during testing I tried to refund myself, using GBP.**

I am using the following to code to cancel said subscriptions

```
public async void cancelPayPalAsync()
{
userManager um = new userManager();
var userID = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
um.Get(userID);
var subid = um.ppID.Trim();
var token = getToken();

using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://api.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/" + subid + "/cancel"))
    {
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

        request.Content = new StringContent("{\n  \"reason\": \"Not satisfied with the service\"\n}");
        request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");

        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
}
```

Has anybody come across this issue? Could it be issues on my end?

Comment: Why don't you use the PayPal SDK? `PaypalHttp` and `PayPalCheckoutSdk`

Comment: Oh, I see. I don't think the SDK supports subscriptions.

Comment: I don't think the sandbox is very reliable. Eg. yesterday, it wouldn't allow me to try and pay and when I tried again this morning, it did so it may resolve itself.

Answer (score 0):

I faced that problem today. In my case I got this error, when I tried to cancel subscription with already cancelled status.